# HTML CSS Multi-Level List Spacing Between Bullet and Text

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to create a multi-level list but I can't get the spacing right between the "bullet' and the text.

For example:
[This is what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxTG6.png)
[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGFZM.png)

As you can see in the second image, the text is aligned to the left regardless of the width of the "bullet" (eg. how lists function in Word).

Here is my code:

```css
div {
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #777777;
}
ul,
ol,
li {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 8pt;
    color: #505050;
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-reset: item;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ol > li {
    display: table;
    counter-increment: item;
    padding-top: 1em;
    color: #282828;
    font-weight: bold;
}
ol > li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 1em;
}
li ol > li {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 0.6em;
    color: #505050;
    font-weight: normal;
}
li ol > li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 1em;
}
li ol ol > li {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 0.6em;
    color: #505050;
    font-weight: normal;
}
li ol ol > li:before {
    content: counter(item, lower-roman) ". ";
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 1em;
}
.boxl {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    width: 735px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxl" style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;">
    <ol>
        <li>
            Heading 1
            <ol>
                <li>
                    Heading 1.1
                    <ol>
                        <li>Roman i</li>
                        <li>Roman ii</li>
                        <li>Roman iii: This is an example of a really long text to see what happens with regards to a hanging indent when the text gets carried over to the next line.</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li>Heading 1.2</li>
                <li>Heading 1.3</li>
                <li>Heading 1.4</li>
                <li>Heading 1.5</li>
                <li>Heading 1.6</li>
                <li>Heading 1.7</li>
                <li>Heading 1.8</li>
                <li>Heading 1.9</li>
                <li>Heading 1.10</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Heading 2</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: table-row` to `ol > li` in css. Like that:

```
ol > li {
    display: table-row;
    ...
}
```

Snippet:

```css
div {
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #777777;
}

ul,
ol,
li {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 8pt;
    color: #505050;
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-reset: item;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ol > li {
    display: table-row;
    counter-increment: item;
    padding-top: 1em;
    color: #282828;
    font-weight: bold;
}

ol > li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

li ol > li {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 0.6em;
    color: #505050;
    font-weight: normal;
}
li ol > li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

li ol ol > li {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 0.6em;
    color: #505050;
    font-weight: normal;
}

li ol ol > li:before {
    content: counter(item, lower-roman) ". ";
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

.boxl {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    width: 735px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxl" style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;">
    <ol>
        <li>
            Heading 1
            <ol>
                <li>
                    Heading 1.1
                    <ol>
                        <li>Roman i</li>
                        <li>Roman ii</li>
                        <li>Roman iii: This is an example of a really long text to see what happens with regards to a hanging indent when the text gets carried over to the next line.</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li>Heading 1.2</li>
                <li>Heading 1.3</li>
                <li>Heading 1.4</li>
                <li>Heading 1.5</li>
                <li>Heading 1.6</li>
                <li>Heading 1.7</li>
                <li>Heading 1.8</li>
                <li>Heading 1.9</li>
                <li>Heading 1.10</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Heading 2</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```